# Import shapefile is not working in pyshp?

Tags: python, pyqgis, python-2.7, pyshp

I am just trying to use "pyshp" package to open shapefile in Python and use the Attribute data for further development.

Firstly I have downloaded pyshp package for python 2.7 and installed it in my computer.
But, whenever I want to import shapefile, I got following error:

```
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named shapefile
```

Comment: Hello Shiuli Pervin. Can you please add your code, it will help us to see what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks:-)I did not yet write any code. I have just tried to check at first in interactive window to check package. I just wrote: "import shapefile" and then I got the error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem must come from the Python PATH. To find out:

- Create a python and copy it into the directory pyshp-master (the one that contains shapefile.py) file.
- Try again to import your shapefile with python.

NB : I test the import it works perfectly. I download pyshp from https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp

Answer (score 7):

Try `pip install pyshp` in your command prompt before trying to run `import shapefile`.

Comment: that worked for me thx.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you are using the right version of pyshp:

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyshp==2.3.0
```

I found my earlier version of pyshp was an old version and didn't import shapefile properly.